# HTML/CSS The div is where it's supposed to be

Tags: html, css

When I put first and second div I made into the the main div it isnt in him, but outside under.
Please paste it in text editor and run it to see the problem and tell me what I did wrong please.

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <title>TEST</title>    
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="second_div"></div>     
    <div id="facebook"></div>
    <div id="twitter"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div.main {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1260px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

* {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#second_div {
    background-color: brown;
    height: 280px;
    width: 1150px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left; 
}

#twitter {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 980px;
    margin-top: 180px
}

#facebook {
    background-color: darkblue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 980px;
}
```

Comment: Why not paste this into a JSfiddle for us yourself. [**JSfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You probably didn't close a tag properly which could cause this problem

Comment: Please confirm that link : is it the output you are having right now: http://jsfiddle.net/prio101prio101/q49zdvjy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.main {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 1260px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#second_div {
    background-color: brown;
    height: 280px;
    width: 1150px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    verticle-align:top;

}

#twitter {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;

    display:inline-block;
    verticle-align:top;
}

#facebook {
    background-color: darkblue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    verticle-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="second_div">
  <div id="facebook"></div>
  <div id="twitter"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="main">
  <div id="second_div">
   <div id="facebook"> </div>
  <div id="twitter"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.main {   background:gray; overflow:hidden; padding:50px;}
#second_div {   background:brown; height:50%; overflow:hidden; border: 4px solid black; padding:20px;}
#facebook { float:left; background:darkblue; width:100px; height:150px; margin-right:20px;}
#twitter { float:left; background:lightblue; height:150px; width:150px;}
```